# Why I can't get the right result using 'if A or B' function in python

Tags: python, if-statement

```
scores = [[100,90,98,88,65],[50,45,99,85,77]]

for i in range(len(scores)):
    for j in range(len(scores[0])):
        if scores[i][j] != min(scores[i]) or scores[i][j] != max(scores[i]):
            print (scores[i][j])
Result
100
90
98
88
65
50
45
99
85
77
```

I want to delete 100(the max value of the first row) and 45(the min value of the second row).
But it doesn't work
I think there's a problem with 'or' function. but I don't know what it is.

Comment: What you need is `and`, not `or`. The value should NOT be equal to the max, AND it should NOT be equal to the min.

Comment: You need to use additional condition as `i==0` with maximum and `i==1` with minimum

Comment: `or` is an operator, not a function. That said, the problem is simply thinking more clearly about the logic. You have two conditions that you're checking: `scores[i][j] != min(scores[i])`, and `scores[i][j] != max(scores[i])`. Do you need either of them to be true? Both of them to be true? Something else? Why?

Comment: Oh my god I get it Thank you !!!!

Comment: Don't use range(len(...)). That is just confusing you more. Just iterate directly on list and use enumerate if u need a counter.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel While I agree with the duplicate, it's a partial one as there are other issues with the code that can't be simply fixed by understanding De Morgan's rules.

Comment: You have a gold badge for [python] too, so please feel free to add/edit the duplicates. I assumed the swap of `or` for `and` resulted from a failure to apply those rules properly, but there are other possible reasons.

Comment: I'd try `[x for x in scores[0] if x != max(scores[0])] + [y for y in scores[1] if y != min(scores[1])] ` and it will produce `[90, 98, 88, 65, 50, 99, 85, 77]`

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check for the value of `i` i.e. row
You want to compare against maximum for `i=0` and minimum against `i=1`, and you need to combine these conditions by `and` operator, then `or` operator.

```py
scores = [[100,90,98,88,65],[50,45,99,85,77]]
for i in range(len(scores)):
    for j in range(len(scores[0])):
        if (i==1 and scores[i][j] != min(scores[i])) or (i==0 and scores[i][j] != max(scores[i])):
            print (scores[i][j])
            
90
98
88
65
50
99
85
77
```